# How to select clicked div and its child anchor element

Tags: jquery

So i have this situation

```
<div class='linkDiv'>
<a href='#' class='link'>
Click here
</a>
</div>
```

and when you click on the linkDiv i want to add the same class to .linkDiv and .link but only the ones clicked

```
$('.linkDiv').click(function(){
//some other code that works fine
//atm i have this
$(this).addClass('active');
$('.link', this).addClass('active');
});
```

How could i select both the clicked div and the child anchor of that div together?

I tried this:

```
$('.linkDiv, .link', this)
```

But it only selected .link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

```
$(".linkDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".link").andSelf().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".linkDiv").click(function() {
 $(this).addClass("active");
 $(this).children().addClass("active");
});
```